# TYPO3 example Typoscript template

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript

What's a minimal example of a working Typoscript template? I've tried the following without success:

```
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0

page.10 < styles.content.get
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample is exactly most basic TYPO3 TypoScript template...

additionally make sure you included `CSS Styled Content (css_styled_content)` from statics.

Comment: That's what I missed! Thanks!

Comment: Just for the record. Nowadays, it's a good idea to not use css_styled_content (CSC) anymore. With TYPO3 7 fluid_styled_content (FSC) got introduced and is way better, since the whole rendering is based on fluid rather than TypoScript. So make sure to solely use FSC. In later versions, CSC will be moved to EXT:compatibility and will sooner or later be gone.